# How do i select correct active serial port in linux?

Tags: java, linux, serial-port, usb

I am trying to communicate with a microcontroller using java.
In windows i simply use "COM4" and my code workes perfectly.
In linux i am trying to use "/dev/ttyUSB0". But gives me an error "Could not find serial port".

I used `dmesg | grep tty` to see active serial port. is this a right method?

how can i solve this issue? I am really new to linux so please explain in simple language

here is my code

```
Enumeration portIdentifiers = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

  CommPortIdentifier portId = null; 
  while (portIdentifiers.hasMoreElements())
  {
      CommPortIdentifier pid = (CommPortIdentifier) portIdentifiers.nextElement();
      if(pid.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL &&
         pid.getName().equals("/dev/ttyUSB0")) 
      {
          portId = pid;
          break;
      }
  }
  if(portId == null)
  {
      System.err.println("Could not find serial port "); // + wantedPortName);
      System.exit(1);
  }
```

Comment: `dmesg` when you insert the device should show the name.

Comment: @Karthik T after using 'dmesg' this came up 'usb 4-2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0'

Comment: Did you load the `usbserial` module?

Comment: @Davide Berra no i didn't. what is it?

Comment: Can you add a `System.out.println( pid.getName());` in your loop, to see if it finds any at all ? Also make sure the permissions are set properly, usually only root can access /dev/ttyUSB0 by default on linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently java communication API do not have linux implementation http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139971.html thats why my code wasn't working.

I installed RXTX library for serial communication and code is working fine now. 
Thanks nos and Olaf Dietsche for the help and support.

Answer (score 1):

`lsusb` should show you the serial to USB converter

```
lsusb | grep -i serial
```

gives on my system

> Bus 001 Device 005: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port

and

```
ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*
```

> crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Feb 18 10:30 /dev/ttyUSB0

I can then access it with

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The user, who needs access to the port, must be in the group `dialout` or whatever group it is in your system. You can add the user with

```
adduser <user-name> dialout
```

Comment: i typed every command you mentioned and i am getting similar outputs

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe Can you add a `System.out.println( pid.getName());` in your loop, to see if it finds any at all ? Also make sure the permissions are set properly, usually only root can access /dev/ttyUSB0 by default on linux.

Comment: @nos yes it appears only root can access /dev/ttyUSB0. so can you tell me more about the permissions? and how do i check them?

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe That's more of the scope for general linux questions though. The line `crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Feb 18 10:30 /dev/ttyUSB0` says that root and the dialout group has read/write access and others have no access. So if you're not the root user, do `chmod o+rw /dev/ttyUSB0` to test it - but you'll have to come up with a more permanent solution.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Dietsche bash: /usr/sbin/adduser: Permission denied

Comment: @nos it says :- chmod: changing permissions of ‘/dev/ttyUSB0’: Operation not permitted

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe You must do `adduser` as root. Don't change the permissions with `chmod`, this will be overwritten the next time you plug in the adapter.

Comment: @OlafDietsche how do i do that? can u please explain?

Comment: @Aditya Ponkshe Well, you can't change the permissions as your own user, that would obviously defeat the purpose of having a permission system. You have to log in as the root user and change the permissions.

Comment: @OlafDietsche i am using Fedora 18 btw

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe I am not familiar with Fedora, but `sudo adduser <user> dialout` from the command line might work.

Comment: @nos how to i switch user to root. on the login screen there is no root option :/

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe You will have to consult a linux forum, perferrably one that deals with your particular linux distro.

Comment: @OlafDietsche i used sudo adduser <user> dialout, it asked me admin password and then a big log of command poped up

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe Then this works different than on Ubuntu. You can also try `su -l -c 'adduser <user> dialout'`.

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe With `sudo` you give the user's password. When you use `su`, you must enter root's password.

Comment: @OlafDietsche both passwords are the same in my case

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe Then I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24696/discussion-between-aditya-ponkshe-and-olaf-dietsche)

Comment: @nos i logged in as root, this chmod o+rw /dev/ttyUSB0 worked

Comment: @nos but still it says "Could not find serial port"

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe  Did you try my first suggestion, and see if it fins any ports at all ?

Comment: @nos yes i did, and i got no output

Comment: @nos i printed all the available portnames and this was printed portList... javax.comm.CommPortEnumerator@90a278

Comment: You printed the wrong thing. Inside the loop (As the first line of code inside the loop) you should print `pid.getName()`. This is just to show if the library finds any com ports at all, or gives them some other name than the "/dev/ttyUSB0" name that you have hard coded. If it doesn't show anything, there something else that doesn't work - I can't help with that.

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe I've been away for a while, looking for the kids.

Comment: @nos can you please specify that in an answer so i can test it and accept the answer if it is working.

Comment: @OlafDietsche after using rxtx problem is solved. thanks for all your help